# @lru_cache decorator: How does it use its previous value to speed it up?

Tags: python, python-3.x, memoization

Doing some leetcode questions and I came across this solution:

```py
class Solution:
    def isValidPalindrome(self, s: str, k: int) -> bool:
        @lru_cache(None)
        def helper(lo, hi, k):
            while lo < hi:
                if s[lo] == s[hi]:
                    lo, hi = lo + 1, hi - 1
                elif k > 0:
                    return helper(lo, hi - 1, k - 1) or helper(lo + 1, hi, k - 1)
                else:
                    return False
            return True
        
        return helper(0, len(s) - 1, k)
```

Well clearly, `@lru_cache` speeds up the process as this solution is accepted but without `@lru_cache`, I get a time limit exceeded. I'm really confused as to how this speeds the process up. From this code, I do not see how it uses stored values as the `lo` and `hi` are unique every time!

Comment: I think the question is not what `@lru_cache` does, but why it helps in this algorithm because OP expects no calls with the same parameters.

Comment: ^^ yes I already know what lru_cache does and read the documentation, I just have no idea how this piece of code is using it to speed up the process

Comment: "lo and hi are unique every time" - we can't be sure of that, as we don't know how this code gets used. But if it really does make a difference, then my guess would be that it probably isn't the case.

Comment: @Matthias: As @ Thierry Lathuille said, using it won't help if the all the calls had different parameter values (if fact it would slow things down) — so that must *not* be the case and the OP is wrong.